# Python script to convert xls to csv with non-ascii

Tags: python, excel, csv, non-ascii-characters

I have a script see below which works fine when the xls contains ascii data. I've tried adding utf-8 at various points but the script still falls over when the xls contain non-ascii.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import xlrd
import csv

book = xlrd.open_workbook('/Users/admin/Documents/PythonScripts/an_excel_file.xls')

# Assuming the fist sheet is of interest 
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# Many options here to control how quotes are handled, etc.
csvWriter = csv.writer(open('/Users/admin/Documents/PythonScripts/a_csv_file.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',') 

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    csvWriter.writerow(sheet.row_values(i))
```

Any ideas how I add this in?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve the problem with UTF-8 data. Hope this helps

```
your_csv_file = open('myfile.csv'), 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
    wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)])
your_csv_file.close()
```

You can prefer to my source code given here: http://www.phuctrancs.info/file_server/convertxls.zip

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback, but it produces a blank csv. I'm basically trying to use Python to open a xls file "file.xls" and resave as a csv. It all works OK unless it has "é" or "'" in the fields. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that it runs but it produce a blank csv?